# Very strange glitch in Mist (Provide maximum fee < estimated fee consumption)

Tags: mist

Okay I really didn't want to have to format my OS, it's like the fifth time now!

My OS: Ubuntu 14

Anyways, I've deployed dozens of Ethereum contracts without problem.  Then, after updatting to newest Ethereum I've been unable to deploy anything since.  This is what happens:

[image: screenshot in mist]

No matter how much ether I send, or slide the bar up and down, nothing changes the provided fee being less than what is required.

I would try "hacking" Mist by editing the source code to manually change values, but so far I haven't been able to do that.

No problem creating wallets by the way..  Except it says it will consume 0 gas (I don't believe it did that before)  Any ideas what I should do?  I'll accept "format" as an answer

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also spent a lot of time on this issue, before I realized that the Maximum Fee field is manually editable. Just click on the gas amount (153,....) and type the amount you think is appropriate.

Comment: Can confirm this works